# Compare key=value pairs from a text file to expected values

Tags: bash, shell

I am completely new to bash and was wondering if somebody could help with the following.

I want to read data from a file (`/etc/sysctl.conf`) and sort them into an array. However, I don't want to read all values only certain values, example below.

```
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout
```

I then want to compare these values to a predefined set (example below).

```
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 0 
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 120
```

And then output whether or not these values match.

Comment: I'm a little unclear what you mean by "sort" in this context. Is there any actual sorting going on?

Comment: BTW, note that often, this kind of question would be rejected as too broad to be on-topic for being too much "please write a program that does thing-X for me", instead of "I tried to write a program to do thing-X, but it did thing-Y instead". Showing what you tried and the specific problem you encountered along the way is always a good idea, as described in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [mre] definition.

Answer (score 1):

An associative array, created with `declare -A`, is bash's equivalent to what other languages might call a "dict", or "map" (with strings as both keys and values). As such, it's appropriate for key/value pairs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[0-3].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0+ required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

# define an associative array mapping your expected keys to values
declare -A expected_values=(
  [net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse]=0
  [net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle]=0
  [net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout]=120
)
declare -A matches_seen=( )                # track which of the values are actually set
mismatches_seen=0                          # initialize flag: no mismatches yet seen

while IFS='= ' read -r key value; do
  expected_value=${expected_values[$key]}  # look up expected value if any exists
  [[ $expected_value ]] || continue        # ignore any lines we don't care about

  if [[ $value = "$expected_value" ]]; then
    echo "GOOD: $key matches expected value of <$expected_value>" >&2
    matches_seen[$key]=1                   # record that we really saw this one
  else
    echo "BAD: $key is expected to be <$expected_value>, but actually is <$value>" >&2
    mismatches_seen=1                      # set mismatches-seen flag
  fi
done </etc/sysctl.conf

# Make sure that we actually saw all the values we expected
# could iterate over the keys to figure out exactly which ones are missing if you cared.
if (( ${#matches_seen[@]} != ${#expected_values[@]} )); then
  echo "ERROR: only ${#matches_seen[@]} of ${#expected_values[@]} values present" >&2
  exit 1
fi

exit "$mismatches_seen"                    # failed exit status if any mismatches seen
```

You could avoid needing `matches_seen` if you removed items from `expected_values` as they're matched (such that any key left in `expected_values` would reflect an error), but that would mean you'd lose the ability to handle values that are present more than once in the file.